# round number to nearest ten thousand

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I have a problem here. I need a function that takes a number between 20 000 - 350 000 and rounds that number to the nearest ten thousand. Im actually quite clue less here.

I want it to work like:

if the function receives the number 120 435 it should return 120 000 wich is the nearest ten thousand etc..

Anyone having an idea here?

Answer (score 7):

```
function round($input:Number, $round:int = 10000):int
{
    var round = Math.round($input / $round);
    return round * $round;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!

i used your function but made it a bit shorter (not that yours are long)

function toNearestTenThousand(val) {
    return Math.round(val/10000) * 10000;
}